# Convert YUV Image into greyscale Image - Same Result as RGB to Grayscale?

Tags: android, image, yuv

I want to do some Imageprocessing on a YUV_420_888 Image and need a greyscale Edition from it. As I read about the YUV Image it should be enough to extract the Y Plane of the Image. In Android I'll try that with this workflow to convert the Y Plane into a byte Array.

```
Image.Plane Y = img.getPlanes()[0];
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Y.getBuffer();
byte[] data = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
byteBuffer.get(data);
```

So as I want to compare this Image I get now with another grayscale Image (or at least a Result of the image processing) I have the Question, Is the grayscale Image I get extracting the Y-Plane nearly the same as a RGB which was turned into grayscale? Or do I have to do some additional processing steps for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `data` you get from Y plane should be the same as if you go through an RGB image.

Answer (score 1):

No, I am using the IR sensor in which I am getting a YUV_420_888 image which is already grey scale. But to convert it in bytes I used following function which gave me error. As per your answer, I took only Y plane and on result it gave me green screen.

```
ByteBuffer[] buffer = new ByteBuffer[1];

            Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();
            buffer[0] = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().duplicate();
            //buffer[1] = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer().duplicate();

            int buffer0_size = buffer[0].remaining();
            //int buffer1_size = buffer[1].remaining();

            buffer[0].clear();
            //buffer[1].clear();

            byte[] buffer0_byte = new byte[buffer0_size];
            //byte[] buffer1_byte = new byte[buffer1_size];

            buffer[0].get(buffer0_byte, 0, buffer0_size);
            //buffer[1].get(buffer1_byte, 0, buffer1_size);

            byte[] byte2 = buffer0_byte;
            //byte2=buffer0_byte;
            //byte2[1]=buffer1_byte;
            image.close();
            mArrayImageBuffer.add(byte2);
```

After dequeing the bytes and goes to funcion:

```
public static byte[] convertYUV420ToNV12(byte[] byteBuffers){
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        outputStream.write( byteBuffers);
        //outputStream.write( byteBuffers[1] );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // outputStream.write( buffer2_byte );

    byte[] rez = outputStream.toByteArray();
    return rez;
}
```